# Filter by combination of (row) pairs

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, tidyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe in a long format and I want to filter pairs based on unique combinations of values. I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
id <- rep(1:4, each=2)
type <- c("blue", "blue", "red", "yellow", "blue", "red", "red", "yellow")
df <- data.frame(id,type)
df
  id   type
1  1   blue
2  1   blue
3  2    red
4  2 yellow
5  3   blue
6  3    red
7  4    red
8  4 yellow
```

Let's say each id is a respondent and type is a combination of treatments. Individual 1 saw two objects, both of them blue; individual 2 saw one red object and a yellow one; and so on.

How do I keep, for example, those that saw the combination "red" and "yellow"? If I filter by the combination "red" and "yellow" the resulting dataset should look like this:

```
  id   type
3  2    red
4  2 yellow
7  4    red
8  4 yellow
```

It should keep respondents number 2 and number 4 (only those that saw the combination "red" and "yellow"). Note that it does not keep respondent number 3 because she saw "blue" and "red" (instead of "red" and "yellow"). How do I do this?

One solution is to reshape the dataset into a wide format, filter it by column, and restack again. But I am sure there is another way to do it without reshaping the dataset. Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution would be:

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- data_frame(
  id = rep(1:4, each = 2),
  type = c("blue", "blue", "red", "yellow", "blue", "red", "red", "yellow")
)

types <- c("red", "yellow")

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(all(types %in% type))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>      id   type
#>   <int>  <chr>
#> 1     2    red
#> 2     2 yellow
#> 3     4    red
#> 4     4 yellow
```

## Update

Allowing for the equal combinations, e.g. `blue`, `blue`, we have to change the filter-call to the following:

```r
types2 <- c("blue", "blue")

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(sum(types2 == type) == length(types2))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#> # Groups:   id [1]
#>      id  type
#>   <int> <chr>
#> 1     1  blue
#> 2     1  blue
```

This solution also allows different types

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(sum(types == type) == length(types))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>      id   type
#>   <int>  <chr>
#> 1     2    red
#> 2     2 yellow
#> 3     4    red
#> 4     4 yellow
```

Comment: I posted exactly the same solution a minute later :)

Comment: If I now have to keep combinations with the same colour ("blue", "blue"), will it be the same code? I tried it and it does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 4):

Let's use `all()` to see if all rows within group match a set of values.

```
library(tidyverse)

test_filter <- c("red", "yellow")

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(all(test_filter %in% type))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups: id [2]
id type  
<int> <fctr>
1     2 red   
2     2 yellow
3     4 red   
4     4 yellow
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified your data and did the following.

```
df <- data.frame(id = rep(1:4, each=3),
                 type <- c("blue", "blue", "green", "red", "yellow", "purple",
                           "blue", "orange", "yellow", "yellow", "pink", "red"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

   id   type
1   1   blue
2   1   blue
3   1  green
4   2    red
5   2 yellow
6   2 purple
7   3   blue
8   3 orange
9   3 yellow
10  4 yellow
11  4   pink
12  4    red
```

As you see, there are three observations for each id. id 2 and 4 have both `red` and `yellow`. They also have non-target colors (i.e., purple, and pink). I wanted to preserve these observations. In order to achieve this task, I wrote the following code. The code can be read like this. "For each id, check if there is any `red` and `yellow` using `any()`. When both conditions are TRUE, keep all rows for the id."

```
group_by(df, id) %>%
filter(any(type == "yellow") & any(type == "red"))

   id   type
4   2    red
5   2 yellow
6   2 purple
10  4 yellow
11  4   pink
12  4    red
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, type1 := shift(type, type = "lag"), by = id]
df1 <- df[type == "yellow" & type1 == "red", id]
df <- df[id %in% df1, ]
df[, type1 := NULL]
```

It gives:

```
   id   type
1:  2    red
2:  2 yellow
3:  4    red
4:  4 yellow
```