# condition on multiple rows and multiple columns by ID in r long format table

Tags: r, long-format-data

I have a table in long format like follows:

```
dt <- data.table(ID=c(rep(1,3),rep(2,2)), time=c(1:3,1,2), x=c("N","N","Y","Y","N"), z=c(NA,NA,"YY",NA,NA))
dt
   ID time x    z
1:  1    1 N <NA>
2:  1    2 N <NA>
3:  1    3 Y   YY
4:  2    1 Y <NA>
5:  2    2 N <NA>
```

Now, for IDs that answered in times 1 and 3, I want to create a variable based on two possible combinations: if `x=Y` (in time 1) or `z=YY` (in time 3), `group` should be Y in both times 1 and 3 (but not in time 2, which should be `NA`).

Hence, the desired output is:

```
   ID time x    z group
1:  1    1 N <NA>     Y
2:  1    2 N <NA>  <NA>
3:  1    3 Y   YY     Y
4:  2    1 Y <NA>  <NA>
5:  2    2 N <NA>  <NA>
```

I wrote the code below, but I didn't get the results I expected:

```
setDT(dt)[ID==1, group := ifelse((time==1 & x=="Y") | (time==3 & z=="YY"), "Y", "N"), by=ID][
          time==2, group := NA]
dt
   ID time x    z group
1:  1    1 N <NA>     N
2:  1    2 N <NA>  <NA>
3:  1    3 Y   YY     Y
4:  2    1 Y <NA>  <NA>
5:  2    2 N <NA>  <NA>
```

For `ID=1`, `group` should be `Y` at times 1 and 3, but it takes the value `N`at time 1 because `x=N`.

I've tried `%in%` instead of `==` but it didn't solve the problem.

Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear which is the logic to create the `group` variable. Please, describe it in words and not in code (especially since it looks like your code does not produce the desired output). Plus, you say that you "want them to be constant by ID", but in your desired output for the ID=1 you have both `NA` and `Y` as `group`. Please clarify.

Comment: Agree with @nicola the goal is not clear, but for now based on your expected outcome if you want row 1: to be group Y shouldn't you change (time==1 & x=="Y") to (time==1 & x=="N")?

Comment: thank you @nicola. I've edited my question to clarify what I want.

Comment: Why the fourth row is `NA`? It has `time==1` and `x=="Y"`.

Comment: @nicola, the fourth row is `NA` because `ID=2` doesn't have an answer at `time=3`. The variable `group` is just for IDs that answered at both times 1 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answers to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48225304/filter-by-combination-of-row-pairs) I figured out how to get the desired output:

```
setDT(dt)[ID==1, group := ifelse(any(x[time==1]=="Y") | any(z[time==3]=="YY"), "Y", "N"), by=ID][
          time==2, group := NA]

dt
   ID time x    z group
1:  1    1 N <NA>     Y
2:  1    2 N <NA>  <NA>
3:  1    3 Y   YY     Y
4:  2    1 Y <NA>  <NA>
5:  2    2 N <NA>  <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
dt$group <- ifelse((dt$time  == 1 & dt$x == "N") | (dt$time == 3 & dt$z == "YY"), dt$x, NA)
```

Or, using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>% 
  mutate(group = ifelse((time  == 1 & x == "N") | (time == 3 & z == "YY"), x, NA))
```

In both cases:

```
   ID time x    z group
1:  1    1 N <NA>     N
2:  1    2 N <NA>  <NA>
3:  1    3 Y   YY     Y
4:  2    1 Y <NA>  <NA>
5:  2    2 N <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: I get this same result with my code, but what I want is `group=Y` for `ID=1` at `time=1` and `time=3`. The general rule is: for each ID, `group` should take the value `Y` (at times 1 and 3) if `x=Y` at time 1 or `z=YY` at time 3.