# Cross checking columns from excel of different lengths in R

Tags: r, excel, sorting

I want a list where columns `policynum` and `policynumber`, in a dataframe `df` are the same. The only way i know how to go about this is with the code below:

```
dft <- df[df$PolicyNum %in% df1$policynumber]
```

The issue is that `policynum` and `policynumber` are different lengths. If anyone has any suggestions that would be so helpful!

**Update to clarify:** I am trying to match the policy number column of each data frame and collect as dft the rows where the policy numbers match.

Comment: Take a look at `match`

Comment: What do you mean by 'the same'? Are you wanting to match `policynum` and `policynumber` according to matching values of those two columns?

Comment: @kpm Yes, exactly! Sorry to be unclear. I only want the columns where policynum = policynumber but they are columns of different lengths.

Comment: Hard to help specifically because its not clear how you want to match. There is a post here that might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48225304/filter-by-combination-of-row-pairs

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just missing a comma. It shouldn't matter if the length of two dataframes are different here.

```
#Add comma at the end of df$policynumber

dft <- df[df$PolicyNum %in% df1$policynumber, ]
```

**Example:**

```
df <- data.frame(policynum = c("E", "B", "C", "D"))
df1 <- data.frame(policynumber = c("A", "E", "F", "G", "B"))

#Matching letters
dft <- df[df$policynum %in% df1$policynumber,]

> dft
[1] "E" "B"
```